# Big delay in executing scripts in Cordova app on init

Tags: javascript, cordova, webview

I'm trying to understand why my Cordova app takes a long time to load.
I've included a screenshot of the first 10 seconds of my app init, and you can see a massive ~4s gap in between the purple and red lines when nothing is happening at all.

[image: app-init-chrome-trace]

The first segment (0 - 2.5s, from the left edge to the purple line) loads my app's scripts and CSS (as specified in the HTML file), and the third segment (6.5s - end, from the red line to the right edge) is where my scripts get evaluated (not including cordova.js). The structure of my HTML is like this:

```
<head>
  <!-- meta tags and link tags -->
</head>
<body>
  <!-- my HTML -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <!-- then my scripts -->
  <script src="path/to/file.js"></script>
</body>
```

The third segment starts with the execution of cordova.js. Any ideas as to why there's that big delay between the purple and red lines?